# is there a way to print a value if it's closer to the value I set?

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to print multiple data values by least to greatest value and I'm wondering if there's a way to do it. like I want to print the input value and the sorting condition is that if any of the input value is close to 1, it would be printed first followed by the rest depending their closeness to 1. for example.

ps `Arrays.sort();` would mess up the code I'm making that's why I'm asking if there's a way to print a value first if it's close to 1 or any value I set in a condition.

giving me java language answers would pretty much help me aside from any other language.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] at = new int[5];

for(int a = 0;a<5;a++){
  System.out.print("Enter number: ");
  at[a]=sc.nextInt();
  System.out.println();
}

for(int b = 0;b<5;b++){
  if(at[b]________){ //what condition should I put here? read from above to know what kind of condition I want. Thanks
  System.out.println(at[b]);
  }
}
```

if the input values were
90
30
70
80
50

the output should be

30
50
70
80
90

Comment: "it would be printed first followed by the rest depending their closeness to 1." So you just want to sort the array? Why not use `sort`? If you don't want it to modify the array, make a copy of it first.

Comment: So you want to sort the values by their distance from the reference value (e.g. 1)? What is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: *or any value I set in a condition* Please show an example of what you mean

Comment: I don't wanna use sort for there are other values intact with the value I'm going to use on the condition which is in the array. For example if the user inputs his id number, arrival time and exit time, and I want to sort it by using their arrival time the one who arrived early will be printed first on top along with his/her id number, arrival time and exit time followed by the next early person, you get it?

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing

```
for(int b = 0;b<5;b++){
 if(at[b]________){ //what condition should I put here? read from above to know what kind of condition I want. Thanks
  System.out.println(at[b]);
  }
}
```

with

```
IntStream.of( at ).mapToObj(Offset::new).sorted((a,b) -> { return Math.abs( a.value - center ) - Math.abs( b.value - center );} ).mapToInt( x -> x.value ).forEach( System.out::println);;
```

you'll also need a helper class like so

```
public static class Offset {
    public int value = 0;
    Offset( int value ) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

It'll leave the original array order intact, and still print it in ascending order.

Please note that the comparator takes into account only distance from **center value**, so both negative and positive offsets are equal.

Cheers